# Z3950 PresentResponse for OPAC

Tags: z39.50

Any idea how I can set the OPACRecord object on PresentResponse in Z39.50? PresentResponse only accepts Records which is a list of NamePlusRecords and each NamePlusRecord object only allows an External object. Any inputs would be helpful. Thanks!

Ref:
https://www.loc.gov/z3950/agency/asn1.html#OPACRecord

Comment: We need more details.  Q: It sounds like you're calling a REST API that implements Z39.50, correct?  Q: which library are you using?  What language are you programming in/what framework are you using?  Q: Do you have any example code you can post?

Comment: Updated the library being used and i'm implementing this in Java. My response object has both bib data and holding data. OPACRecord object listed in the above URL support both bibData and holdings data. But, I don't see a way to set this OPACRecord object in PresentResponse as NamePlusRecord. Please suggest if need additional info. Thanks!